# Best Fan position for maximum airflow in a Vent

Tags: airflow, air

I need to add a simple ventilation duct to my room.

The purpose is to draw stale air from the room to the outside.

Is it better to place the fan at the intake (position 1) or at the output end (position 2) for maximum air flow?  Does fan position make a difference?

I attach a sketch for clarity.

Thanks!
[image: Best Fan position for Max Airflow]

Comment: A fan works more efficiently when it is placed on the exhaust side of the duct (position 1). The shock losses are lower & the exhaust air is not initially confined to a duct before it can expand upon reaching the atmosphere outside. In position 1 the air can immediately begin to expand when leaving the fan. It's probably not practical in your situation, but an [evasee](http://vlabs.iitkgp.ernet.in/mv/exp10/index.html) attached to the exhaust of the fan in position 1, would improve fan performance.

Comment: thanks so much for the info, I will use position 1 for the exhaust fan.  No room for a conical frustum.  Fan position 2 is a heater/fan.  The idea is to use timer switches to alternate between heating/pumping position 1) air into the room and extracting (position 2) stale air in cycles. This temporary system actually fits into the gap of secondary glazing. If I had the time, I  would experiment using a bitcoin miner to heat the air inflow....